# Nginx vhost config doesn't work with SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

I try to get my vhost working with my SSL cert on Nginx.

I just get error 102 connection refused when i try to access the site!

```
 server {
    listen   80;
    root /var/storage/linusodenring.se/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name linusodenring.se www.linusodenring.se;
location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
```

}

```
 server {
 listen   443;
    root /var/storage/linusodenring.se/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name linusodenring.se;
 ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /secret/ssl_linusodenring.se/linusodenringse.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /secret/ssl_linusodenring.se/linusodenringse.key;
keepalive_timeout        50;
location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
```

}

My vhost config! Notice they are in the same file just Serverfault that is bugged!

Comment: What is output of `nginx -t`. Did you restart you nginx process? Did you check nginx error.log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed SSL in Nginx and had it working on the first try by following the Ars Technica article [Web served, part 2: Securing things with SSL/TLS](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/11/securing-your-web-server-with-ssltls/).